# Compare values for consecutive dates of same month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
ID Value Date
1   10   2017-10-02 02:50:04.480
2   20   2017-10-01 07:28:53.593
3   30   2017-09-30 23:59:59.000
4   40   2017-09-30 23:59:59.000
5   50   2017-09-30 02:36:07.520
```

I compare Value with previous date. But, I don't need compare result between first day in current month and last day in previous month. For this table, I don't need to compare result between `2017-10-01 07:28:53.593 and 2017-09-30 23:59:59.000` How it can be done?

Result table for this example:

```
ID Value Date                      Diff
1   10   2017-10-02 02:50:04.480   10
2   20   2017-10-01 07:28:53.593   NULL
3   30   2017-09-30 23:59:59.000   10
4   40   2017-09-29 23:59:59.000   10
5   50   2017-09-28 02:36:07.520   NULL
```

Comment: (1) The September dates in the first table are all the same.  (2) What if a date is skipped?  (3) What if there are two rows for the same date?

Answer (score 1):

you can use a query like below

```
select *,
diff=LEAD(Value) OVER( PARTITION BY Month(Date),Year(Date) ORDER BY Date desc)-Value
from t 
order by id asc
```

<kbd>**[see working demo](http://rextester.com/SWME48837)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use this.

```
SELECT * , 
    LEAD(Value) OVER( PARTITION BY DATEPART(YEAR,[Date]), DATEPART(MONTH,[Date]) ORDER BY ID ) - Value AS Diff 
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY ID
```